# Mapping Nest response to a C# object

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I am trying to map a nest response to a c# object and having little luck.

My query returns the result from

```
var resp = Eclient.Search<dynamic>(q => q
    .Type("movies")
    .From(0)
    .Size(20)
    .QueryRaw(queryString));
```

How can I map the response to a C# object? 
It needs to be dynamic, i.e there are arrays that wary in length in the response.

Answer (score 0):

Serialize a dynamic object to JSON and then deserialize a string to a proper C# object. But that would be totally inefficient. Why not pass a dynamic object around or just do manual mapping?

Comment: Can you explain in more detail?

Comment: I just realized - cant you just replace `Eclient.Search<dynamic>` with `Eclient.Search<MyType>`?

Comment: will the resp variable contain an instance of MyType then?

Comment: `resp.Response` will